# Authenticating using a Hash password store in the database using ASP.net

Tags: c#, authentication, hash, salt

Please Need help to check user Authenticating password. When I created the user I used hash + salt to encrypt the password before storage in the database. I want the user to be able to login with the registered password, I am new to Hash.

Html

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Width="267px"   TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="267px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="Login_Click" 
                Width="111px" />
```

Hash Function used

```
    public String CreatedSalt(int size)
    {
      var rng = new    System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var buff = new byte[size];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
    }

    public String GenerateSHA256Hash(String input, String salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha256hashstring = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = sha256hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
```

Login.cs

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd =  con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AdminID FROM   [User]  WHERE  StaffEmail = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND StaffPassword ='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Session["AdminID"] = dr["AdminID"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect("AppointmentMenu.aspx");
    }

    Response.Write("<script>alert('Please check your Username or Password')</script>");
```

Comment: When a user logs in, you hash the login password and compare it with hashed password from the database. If it matches, authenticate = true.

Comment: You're going to need to keep the salt you used to hash each password.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: So, if I use a "random" salt to store the password, then, at some later date, the user tries to log in - How do I hash the new login attempt in such a way as to compare it to the stored hashed password?  Since I no longer have the salt I used to store the password in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

I thing, you need solve some others problems before hashing..

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AdminID FROM   [User]  WHERE  StaffEmail = @userName AND StaffPassword =@pwd";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", txtPassword.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count >0)
        {
            Session["AdminID"] = dt.Rows[0]["AdminID"].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("AppointmentMenu.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please check your Username or Password')</script>");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hash the input form `txtPassword.Text` before sending it to the database, with the same methods you used in the sign up:

```
    string hashedPass = GenerateSHA256Hash(txtPassword.Text, CreatedSalt(128));
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AdminID FROM  [User]  WHERE  StaffEmail = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND StaffPassword ='" + hashedPass + "'";
```

Besides that, the `CreateSalt` method should be private, accessed only by `GenerateSHA256Hash`, that should get only one `string input` argument. Then, for any input, the `GenerateSHA256Hash` should call the `CreateSalt` method.

Comment: Hi Akali The Function (CreatedSal GenerateSHA256Hash) are in the register page. How can I have access to the function 
 to use them in the login page. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi man.
What you need to do is to add a static class (MyHashing.cs for ex.) to your application (at your App_Code folder), and put the two hashing methods from the registration page into that class. That way, the methods will be accessable both from the sign up page and from the login page:

hashedPass = MyHashing.GenerateSHA256Hash(txtPassword.Text);